# What is eating my vine?

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, leaves, indoors, pests

I’m trying to figure out what is getting at my indoor vine plant. I’ve never seen bites like these before, but found them after a week away on holiday. What do they look like to you? I have a couple of potential causes in mind:

Suspect #1 I have a wood mouse living in the wall that my property manager is trying to help block. He doesn’t usually get into anything though, usually just unsuccessfully explores for crumbs at night. Certainly never seen signs of him climbing up the counters or food racks where my plant is located. Plus I’ve never heard of mice getting into house plants?

Suspect #2 Could be some sort of soil bug. I am re-propagating the vine today because there was some rot at the stem. However, the bites are located at the centre of the stem length, not anywhere near the pot. No other plants seem infested.

Plant nibbles:
[image: Plant nibbles]

More plant nibbles:
[image: more nibbles]

Nibble piece fell off?
[image: nibbled piece fell off?]